# Modifying iterator inside for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, iterator

I have a problem like this:
I got size of array and the array itself (all the elements) and i need to sort the array in the way that first item in array (lets call it key item) is placed so all items smaller then key item go left from key item and all items larger then key item go right form key item, but the items need to be i a same order as they was in declaration like so:
array input:

```
4 7 3 5 6 2 9 1 10 8
```

array output:

```
3 2 1 4 7 5 6 9 10 8
```

so i thought i can just go one time through array and if value is smaller then key item swap them and if value is larger then key item, place that value (item ) at the  end (if there is n items in array place it on n+1 place) and then to shift all items from current index one place to the left like:

```
| 4 | 7 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 1  | 10 | 8 |

| 4 |   | 3 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 1  | 10 | 8 | 7 |

| 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 7 |
```

but like that i would need to after every shifting make iterator stay same (so it can check that place again.
I have a code like this :

```
int u=1;
for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
    if (x[i]<x[u]){
       swap(x[i],x[u]);
       u+=1;
    }else {
        x[i]=x[n];
        for (int k=i;k<n-1;k++){x[k]=x[k+1];}
        i--;
    }
}
```

i think i made a mistake in the swapping part but i cant figure it out.

Comment: Assuming `x` is an array or array-like type, are you sure `x[n]` is a legitimate element in your array? If you have an array `int x[n]` then the last element you can access is `x[n-1];`. You can't place an element beyond the end of an array and expect it to grow to accommodate it.

Comment: i have int x[100] and in input i fill only 10  (out of 101?) places

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be done using the STL's [`std::stable_partition()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) algorithm:

> divides elements into two groups while preserving their relative order

Let it do the hard work for you, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct doPartitionOn
{
    int m_key;

    doPartitionOn(int key) : m_key(key) {}

    bool operator()(int a)
    {
        return (a < m_key);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 2, 9, 1, 10, 8};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::stable_partition(arr, arr+10, doPartitionOn(arr[0]));

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

> 4 7 3 5 6 2 9 1 10 8
>   3 2 1 4 7 5 6 9 10 8

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/GW2mCc)

Or, if using C++11 or later, you can use a lambda instead of a manual functor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 2, 9, 1, 10, 8};

    for(int value: arr)
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::stable_partition(arr, arr+10, [&arr](int a){ return (a < arr[0]); });

    for(int value: arr)
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

> 4 7 3 5 6 2 9 1 10 8
>   3 2 1 4 7 5 6 9 10 8

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/WxIDBG)

Comment: @anakata look at my examples again more carefully. They use only one array and sort it inline, just like you are attempting to do. Did you even try the code I gave you?

Comment: sorry mate i was in hurry.. your code looks good but i wanted to do that without all predefined functions (doPartitionOn)  :)

Comment: @anakata: then I suggest you look at the source code for `std::stable_partition()` to see how it performs its sorting.